# i need share a audio.mp3 From my App to Whatsapp

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When I run the app, it doesn't share audio in whatsapp.

```
pulsante2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

   //condividere
   InputStream inputStream;
   FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
   try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.suono2);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));
        intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share audio"));

        return false;
    }
});
```

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></u‌​ses-permission>` 
so why doesn't it share audio mp3?

Comment: Maybe the URI is wrong? Can you try with `Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3")`?

Comment: fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"))   OR

Comment: Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));

Comment: in second say me ERROR Uri cannot be applicated java.lang.string